# Identify first sign in with Authentication using AD for Microsoft Bot Framework

Tags: botframework, bots, access-token

I would like to give a login successful message to the user when he sign in for the first time. So i need to identify weather the user have used sign card shown to sign in(user have interacted) or system automatically taken the token itself without user intervention. It will be nice we show a successful message user interaction was there. How i can identify weather there was a user interaction or not?

Comment: What language is your bot written in? Please let us know what you've tried so far and link to any documentation/samples you're following

Comment: Are you still working on this?

Comment: yep,Today i got the answer from a different forum

Comment: Which is it? Are you still working on it or has your question been been answered? If it's been answered then you should post the answer as an answer here so you can accept it.

Comment: @KyleDelaney I had posted the lnk to the forum but it was deleted. So the solution I got have been posted asuch without the linkto forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer I found is to find the Activity Type if its event type user have interacted else it’s an automatic signin. You can reverify the connection just established by checking the value of key connectionName in Activity.Value.  The following code will help you.

```
string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(stepContext.Context.Activity.Value, Formatting.Indented);
if (stepContext.Context.Activity.Type is "event")
{
      var conName = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(output)["connectionName"].ToString();
      if (conName ==<Your Connection Name>)
      {
      await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text($"You have successfully Signed In"), cancellationToken);
      await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text($"How can I help you?"), cancellationToken);
     }
 }
```